# Draw polygon on MapBox map in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using [Mapbox for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms) NuGet to implement MapBox on Xamarin forms.

But I am not able to draw polygon on map.

Code:

```
Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation polyline = null;    

           if (polyline == null)
           {
             polyline = new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation
             {
               HexColor = “#ff1234”,
               Width = 100
             };
           }

           // Set coordinates
           List<CompanyGeoFenceVM> cordinates = new List<CompanyGeoFenceVM>();
           var savedCordinates = Preferences.Get(“cordinates”, “”);
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedCordinates))
           {
             cordinates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyGeoFenceVM>>(savedCordinates);
           }

           foreach (var cordinate in cordinates)
           {
             if (polyline.Coordinates == null)
             {
               polyline.Coordinates = new ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position>
                                           { new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(cordinate.Latitude, cordinate.Longitude) };
             }
             else
             {
               (polyline.Coordinates as ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position>)
                           .Add(new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(cordinate.Latitude, cordinate.Longitude));
             }

           }
           List<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation> polylineAnnotations = new List<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation>();
           polylineAnnotations.Add(polyline);

           //show polygon
           map.Polylines = polylineAnnotations;


         map.ZoomLevel = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? 8 : 10;


         Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position position = await NexgenGeocoder.ReverseGeocode(Preferences.Get(“address”, “”));
         map.Center = new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(position.Latitude , position.Longitude);
```

Here i am trying to add the polygon. **cordinate** is variable which has the coodinates required data to process. kindly help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get a specific error or don't you just see the polygon where you expect it to be seen? Also, have you double checked that the coordinates you're getting are around the area of the address you center the map to?

Comment: No error. Yes, I am not able to see polygon on map. Coordinates are correct since same coordinates  are working on google map.

Comment: hello, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: yes, managed to resolve this using Polylines.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you do it? i'm stuck at this, i'm not able to create any type of annotation, marker, polygon, polylines, anything, i'm usin Naxam Mapbox for Xamarin.Forms, if you can tell me what are the nugets you included in your projects, i would be so much apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Included Naxam nuget package and plotted the polygon using Polyline. At last need to add a custom line to complete the Polyline area.

```
 Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation polyline = null;
 ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Annotation> annotations;


 annotations = new ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Annotation>();

//Add Polygon
        if (polyline == null)
        {
          polyline = new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.PolylineAnnotation
          {
            Id = "my_polyline",
            Title = "Polygon",
            HexColor = "#ff1234",
            Width = 1
          };
        }

        foreach (var cordinate in cordinates)
        {
          if (polyline.Coordinates == null)
          {
            polyline.Coordinates = new ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position>
                        { new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(cordinate.Latitude, cordinate.Longitude) };
          }
          else
          {
            (polyline.Coordinates as ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position>)
                          .Add(new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(cordinate.Latitude, cordinate.Longitude));

          }
        }

//We are using polylines so we have to add ending point to line.
        if (polyline.Coordinates != null)
          (polyline.Coordinates as ObservableCollection<Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position>)
                          .Add(new Naxam.Controls.Mapbox.Forms.Position(cordinates[0].Latitude, cordinates[0].Longitude));

       annotations.Add(polyline);

  mapview.Annotations = annotations;
```

Comment: @Ricardo Dias Morais, were you able to solve the problem.